# How can I resolve this light house error in github workflows ? ( Error completed with exit code 1)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, lighthouse

My lighthouse report turn up like this

```
lhci autorun --upload.target=temporary-public-storage --collect.staticDistDir=.
shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
env:
FORCE_COLOR: 1
> ✅  .lighthouseci/ directory writable
Configuration file not found
Chrome installation found
Healthcheck passed!

Started a web server on port 34123...
Running Lighthouse 3 time(s) on http://localhost:34123/index.html
Error: Lighthouse failed with exit code 1
Run #1...failed!
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.14.1/x64/lib/node_modules/@lhci/cli/src/collect/node-runner.js:120:21)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:25 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:25 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:26 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.....
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:26 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.......
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:27 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.........
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:27 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...........
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:28 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.............
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:28 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...............
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:29 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:29 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:30 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.....................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:30 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.......................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:31 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.........................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:31 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...........................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:32 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.............................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:32 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...............................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:33 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:33 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:34 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.....................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:34 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.......................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:35 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.........................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:35 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...........................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:36 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.............................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:36 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...............................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:37 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:37 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:38 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.....................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:38 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.......................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:39 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.........................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:39 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...........................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:40 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.............................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:40 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...............................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:41 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:41 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:42 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.....................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:42 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.......................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:43 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.........................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:43 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...........................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:44 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.............................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:44 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...............................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:45 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.................................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:45 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...................................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:46 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.....................................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:46 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.......................................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:47 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.........................................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:47 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...........................................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:48 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.............................................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:48 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...............................................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:49 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.................................................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:49 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...................................................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:50 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.....................................................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:50 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.......................................................................................................
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:50 GMT ChromeLauncher:error connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:37367
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:50 GMT ChromeLauncher:error Logging contents of /tmp/lighthouse.pILSYwp/chrome-err.log
Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:49:50 GMT ChromeLauncher:error 
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:37367/devtools/browser/7c26091c-d096-4a86-a84c-85f53c75d072
[0227/144925.989931:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[0227/144926.025738:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(393)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.

Unable to connect to Chrome

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I checked for linter errors of my html and css project in my deployment repo and it appears like this. And I also can't enter the link due to prolonged loading time. I try reducing the file sizes of images inside the project to reduce loading time but it still not working and I'm stuck here. Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also having trouble with that in the excersices I'm doing in a Bootcamp and after searching like 20 pages for some information about it, I found that the main problem is the node version you are using for that linter. You might be using more than one linter but for **LightHouse** specifically you would like to use: 
`node-version: 14` ✅ ⬅ This will fix the problem (specifying the version). 
You can change that in your ***.yml*** file, that in my case is named ***"linters.yml"***, you will have something like: 
`- name: Setup Node.js environment
uses: actions/setup-node@v2.5.1
with:
node-version: "18x"` ❌ ⬅ This was the problem (latest version for default). 
Hope this fixed your problem. I'm kinda new to this but I'm great learner and I learn a lot trying to help too.

Answer (score -1):

Use **`continue-on-error: true`**. The steps will continue even if there is any error.

The modified step:

```
 - name: 'Run Lighthouse tests'
   continue-on-error: true
   run: lhci autorun
```

Here are some refs:

- a run, where I tested: https://github.com/maifeeulasad/remanage/actions/runs/5289966584
- the workflow file: https://github.com/maifeeulasad/remanage/actions/runs/5289966584/workflow
- in case you are missing it, here is specific commit: https://github.com/maifeeulasad/remanage/blob/1e9ff4c7ebcb1e11e8dbb5edff0857579ac3cdff/.github/workflows/lighthouse.yml